# Passing local image uri as props in react-native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I'm trying to pass the uri of an image as prop so I can reuse it several times on react-native. However, this current solution prompts me that require should use string literals.

```
const ImageButton = ({ source }) => (
    <Image source={require({ source })} />
);

ImageButton.propTypes = {
     uri: PropTypes.string,
};
```

I've also tried declaring uri as a PropTypes.func, and doing

```
<Image source={{ source }} />
```

but the image doesn't appear. What's the correct implementation of an image uri prop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do separate object for requiring images since it's not possible with dynamically defined strings.

For instance:

```
const assets = {
  imageButton: require('./assets/button.jpg'),
};

const ImageButton = (source) => {
  <Image source={assets[source]} />
}

class MyComponent extends Component(props) {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageButton source={'imageButton'} />
    )
  }  
}
```

Comment: So for that to be possible, all have to be in the same file, right? I'm trying to do such that I'm importing ImageButton from somewhere and just pass it off, but I don't think it's possible since exporting ImageButton with no source just results in no image being rendered.