# How to pass prop for an image stored locally in react-native

Tags: image, react-native, local, react-props, react-image

I tried to pass a prop for the 'require' in IMAGE tag of the react-native component. But, it shows an error "Server code Error 500". The same if I pass a link using URI it works with the props.

Working :

```
<Image
        style={{ width: 70, height: 61 }}
        source={{ uri: imgCode }}
      />


imgCode="https://i.imgur.com/edgLzLO.png"
```

Need a fix:

```
<Image
          style={{ width: 70, height: 61 }}
          source={require('./images/header_arrow.png')}
        />

imgCode="./images/batter_logo.png"
```

Comment: Hmmm, it works for me using `require` as the value of `source`. Kinda weird, but it works. Are you sure that's the correct path to the image?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704415/passing-local-image-uri-as-props-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image
    style={{ width: 70, height: 61 }}
    source={require({ uri: imgCode })}
  />


imgCode="https://i.imgur.com/edgLzLO.png"
```

Try this This may work